# Using sweetalerts2 with api calls

Tags: reactjs, express, sweetalert2

I have my frontend in react and backend in express, i want to use sweetalerts2 on the sign up/sign in page. I tried searching around the internet about how would I display an error alert using sweetalerts2, when the credentials are wrong, but I couldn't find anything. Could anybody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sweetalert2-react-content](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2-react-content) package, like in this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/p9oz71052q):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import withReactContent from "sweetalert2-react-content";

const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal);

class App extends React.Component {

  myAwesomeLoginFunction() {
    // make your API call here.
    // let's say it returns a status code of 200 if the login credentials are correct
    const status = 200;

    if (status === 200) {
      MySwal.fire({
        title: <p>Hello World</p>,
        type: "success",
        customClass: "animated tada"
      });
    } else {
      MySwal.fire({
        title: <p>Wrong password/email</p>,
        type: "error",
        customClass: "animated tada"
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>Hello world!</h2>
        <button onClick={this.myAwesomeLoginFunction.bind(this)}>Login</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And there are other React wrappers for sweetAlert2, like:

- [sweetalert2-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweetalert2-react)
- [react-bootstrap-sweetalert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-sweetalert)